error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find expected key
I am trying to create a redis helm chart via a module within a github workflow. The problem seems to be in the helm-values.yaml file in the module.
It's an error converting YAML to JSON: yaml.
I have a workflow in github that executes a command that terraform apply a module that is in another github repo, in this module I have a helm-values.yaml that looks like this:
architecture: standalone

fullnameOverride: ${redis_deployment_name}
auth:
  password: ${redis_admin_password}
# auth:
#   existingSecret: redis
#   existingSecretPasswordKey: redis-password

master:
  ${ indent(2, redis_affinity) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_nodeSelector) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_default_tolerations) }
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 350m
      memory: 700Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi

pdb:
  enabled: true

# Explicit activation of Redis Stream
redisStreamEnabled: true

but I get this error:
 Error: ---> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: did not find expected key architecture: standalone

I changed the manifest file to look like this:
## @param architecture; architecture. Allowed: `standalone` or `replication`
##
architecture: standalone

fullnameOverride: ${redis_deployment_name}
auth:
  password: ${redis_admin_password}
# auth:
#   existingSecret: redis
#   existingSecretPasswordKey: redis-password
master:
  ${ indent(2, redis_affinity) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_nodeSelector) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_default_tolerations) }
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 350m
      memory: 700Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi
pdb:
  enabled: true

# Explicit activation of Redis Stream
redisStreamEnabled: true

But now i'm getting this error:
 Error: ---> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: did not find expected key ## @param architecture; architecture. Allowed: `standalone` or `replication`

So i changed one more time to this:
---
# Parameter info: architecture. Allowed values: `standalone` or `replication`

architecture: standalone

fullnameOverride: ${redis_deployment_name}
auth:
  password: ${redis_admin_password}
# auth:
#   existingSecret: redis
#   existingSecretPasswordKey: redis-password

master:
  ${ indent(2, redis_affinity) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_nodeSelector) }
  ${ indent(2, redis_default_tolerations) }
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 350m
      memory: 700Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi

pdb:
  enabled: true

# Explicit activation of Redis Stream
redisStreamEnabled: true


But now I get this error:
 Error: ---> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find expected key ---
│ # Parameter info: architecture. Allowed values: `standalone` or `replication`

Every time I change the code, I get errors related to the first line even if it is a comment.
I used **yamllint **to verify, the code works locally when i don't call it as a module, when i do a terraform apply directly in the root module.
What seems to be the problem?
This is the code of the terraform module:
resource "helm_release" "redis" {
    timeout   = 240
    name      = "redis"
    namespace = var.namespace
    chart     = "oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/redis"
    version   = var.helm_chart_version
    values = [templatefile("${path.module}/manifests/redis-values.yaml", {
      redis_deployment_name     = var.redis_deployment_name
      redis_affinity            = var.redis_affinity
      redis_nodeSelector        = var.redis_nodeSelector
      redis_default_tolerations = var.redis_default_tolerations
      redis_admin_password      = var.redis_admin_password
    })]
}

and this is how I'm calling it:
module "redis" {
    source = "git::https......"
    namespace                 = var.namespace
    redis_deployment_name     = var.redis_deployment_name
    redis_affinity            = var.redis_affinity
    redis_nodeSelector        = var.redis_nodeSelector
    redis_default_tolerations = var.redis_default_tolerations
    redis_admin_password      = "toto"
}

These are screenshots from the outout of the github workflow:




Can you provide minimal terraform code to reproduce this issue? ... also the output of terraform plan can be very useful

I have added the terraform code, the output of the terraform plan is the error in the description.

See that is a curve ball, you are using templatefile are you sure the output of that is valid? ... can you also share more output from the terraform plan??

Just to test, can you hard code all the values in the yaml files and instead of templatefile use plain file like the example here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#example-usage---chart-repository

I have added a screenshot for the pipeline's output, as you can se the output variables are being parsed and read correctly with the correct values.

I can't be sure of anything with those screenshots ... just to discard that templatefile could be a problem, can you test without it?

The problem with file is that it can only accept one argument!
It should be something like that:
values = [file("${path.module}/manifests/redis-values.yaml")]
But, as you can see in my code i'm calling other vars from the var file, I need it to be generic because i'm using it as a module.
I can't hardcode the values :(

Yes, we know file can accept only one arg... this is to isolate the problem ... there are 3 potential candidates for this problem: _ _ _ 1 - the provider code of helm_release _ _ _ 2 - the output of templatefile _ _ _ 3 - the contents of the yaml file

... and I'm asking you to try because with the information you have provided we can not reproduce the problem, since this is on GitHub maybe post a link to the repo, if it is private just create a new one that reproduces the issues with mock data

I had to remove all the commented code and use yamllint to validate the code.
